# Generating a minitest :spec test for an existing controller for functional testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, minitest

I have a controller and I want to generate a minitest -spec test for that controller for functional testing.

I know testfiles get generated upon controller or model generation, but ...
Is there a rails generator for just creating a test with -spec?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [minitest-rails](https://github.com/blowmage/minitest-rails) gem adds `--spec` argument to do this.

```
$ rails generate controller Thing --spec
```

Comment: is there a standalone generator, ah nevermind rails needs to know where to put the tests so forget about it.

Comment: migrations complain when trying to generate spec for existing model

Answer (score 0):

For generate test code for exiting controller you can use below command

```
bin/rails generate test_unit:controller <controller_name>
```

generate the test scaffold code for each of the seven default actions, you can use the following command

```
bin/rails generate test_unit:scaffold <controller_name>
```